# When Microsoft Security Updates are "re-released" is the most recent patch cumulative?

Tags: windows, windows-update, update, knowledge-base

While trying to script deployment of .msu's I realized that certain KB articles had multiple releases.  One example of this is KB2524426.

KB2524426 was released May 2011 and re-released June 2011.  There are similar other re-releases KB2536276.

Since the KB article is part of the file name I used this thinking that each contained a unique update (.msu).  Now that I know this is not the case, I'm trying to figure out if taking the most recent KB release will suffice when creating/deploying an update package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The re-release corrects issues that appear once the patch is released.  I would say its only cumulative if it says so in the technotes released to describe the patch.

Comment: Makes sense.  Since the subsequent releases are meant to improve or correct the first release, can you think of any case in which using just the most recent release would not be enough?

Comment: It depends on what the re-release fixes.  You would want to read the technote of the re-release to see why they're re-releasing the patch and whether or not it applies to your environment.